# Add ArrayBuffer Element via def in Scala

Tags: scala

I am curious as to how to add an ArrayBuffer element via a `def`. E.g.

```
def addToArray[T](data: ArrayBuffer[T]): ArrayBuffer[T] = {
      return(data += T("XYZ"))
}
```

I tried this but no go. I assume we cannot do this generically, but I would like to know how to do this. If I do this, `return(new ArrayBuffer[T]())`, it works. Not the most difficult but somehow escaping me.

Comment: What di you expected `T("XYZ")` to do?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Hi, it's just a contrived example to add an element to existing ArrayBuffer[T] represented by data. e.g. 3 items of class T, then 4 items. Seems fine inline, but via defs not so easy.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I cannot really find a suitable  reference for this type of stuff.

Comment: If you want to use an specific type `T` then why use a type parameter of the same name?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez you will have to elaborate pls

Comment: I think the issue is wrong way of thinking from my side: Scala does not support pass-by-reference.

Comment: I really don't understand what is your question: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/96i2xOeqRyipO5yCj1Adbg/3

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez  pass an ArrayBuffer[t] in, add an item to it via a def, so it it is 1 entry longer. Just using a def, what could be so odd about that? I AM FROM PASCAL, MODULA university zeitgeest

Comment: There is nothing odd about the question other than is just as basic as printing hello world, thus I don't understand why are you even asking it. What you want to do just works if you use the right syntax as I showed in the **Scastie** I shared which seems you didn't check, please do. - Now, you either just have a  syntax problem which I hope the link would fix, or you have a more complex question than just adding an element to a mutable collection; if the latter then we do not have enough context to understand what you need and what si wrong.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez  I got the answer, which I was wanting as you can see. But I started out as it so happens in a different way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just give the `def` your generic buffer and the element you want to add then return it:

```
  def addToArrayBuffer[T](data: ArrayBuffer[T], elem: T): ArrayBuffer[T] = {
    data += elem
    data
  }
  println(addToArrayBuffer(ArrayBuffer(1, 2, 30), 4)) // ArrayBuffer(1, 2, 30, 4)
```

If you are not passing the element you want to add as a parameter to the `def`, then you can't add it inside the `def`. The idea is that you cannot create an instance of a *type parameter*, because instantiation requires a constructor which is unavailable if the type is unknown. This restriction is mentioned in the Java generics spec [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#):

> *Cannot Create Instances of Type Parameters:* You cannot create an
> instance of a type parameter. For example, the following code causes a
> compile-time error:

```
public static <E> void append(List<E> list) {
    E elem = new E();  // compile-time error
    list.add(elem);
}
```

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java) also explains this very nicely:

> *Java generics differ from C++ templates.* Java generics generate only
> one compiled version of a generic class or function regardless of the
> number of parameterizing types used. Furthermore, the Java run-time
> environment does not need to know which parameterized type is used
> because the type information is validated at compile-time and is not
> included in the compiled code. Consequently, instantiating a Java
> class of a parameterized type is impossible because instantiation
> requires a call to a constructor, which is unavailable if the type is
> unknown.

**Note** that there might be a workaround to this using *reflection*, which is further detailed in the spec.

Comment: OK that is actually what I was working towards, but wondering why data += T("ZZZZZZ") does not work?  Instead of data += elem

Comment: @thebluephantom because `T("ZZZZZZ")` doesn't make any sense in the context of your code, which is why I asked what you wanted it to do. - Now, note that the method in this answer is basically useless since it is even longer than just calling `+=` when you need it, and is not abstracting anything.

Comment: I updated my answer to address you concern. The idea is you can't instantiate an unknown type, because you require a constructor, which is unavailable if the type is unknown. So `T("ZZZZZZ")` does not compile. Luis is right.